# How to sort wrapper which has custom sobject

Tags: apex

I want to sort a custom wrapper list. A piece of code is shown below.

```
public List<Subscription__c> subs;  
public TerritoryBusinessUnit__c tlBU;

public class wrap {

        public boolean selection { set; get; }
        public subscription__c sub { set; get; }

        public wrap(boolean sel, subscription__c s) {

            selection = sel;
            sub = s;
        }
    }

public List<wrap> wrapls = new List<wrap>();

    public List<wrap> subList { 
        set; 
        get{
            return wrapls;
        } 
    }

public void Laodsubscriptions()
{
  subs=[some condition here]

tlBU=[SELECT ID,Name, TerritoryLabel__c, MID__c, FetchType__c,Address__c
                    FROM TerritoryBusinessUnit__c
                    WHERE MID__c=:ApexPages.currentpage().getparameters().get('mid')];

if(tlBu.FetchType__c == 'L')
{
  //some logic
}

wraps.sort();
}
```

**Error:**

> One or more of the items in this list is not Comparable.

Please let me know what best can be done to resolve this.

Answer (score 1):

This interface is covered in the `Apex Developer Guide`:

> ## [Comparable Interface](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_comparable.htm)
>
> Adds sorting support for Lists that contain non-primitive types, that is, Lists of user-defined types.
>
> ```
> global class Employee implements Comparable {
>
>     public Long id;
>     public String name;
>     public String phone;
>     
>     // Constructor
>     public Employee(Long i, String n, String p) {
>         id = i;
>         name = n;
>         phone = p;
>     }
>     
>     // Implement the compareTo() method
>     global Integer compareTo(Object compareTo) {
>         Employee compareToEmp = (Employee)compareTo;
>         if (id == compareToEmp.id) return 0;
>         if (id > compareToEmp.id) return 1;
>         return -1;        
>     }
> }
> ```

Please, never use the `global` access modifier unless you know of a solid reason you need it. Replace `global` with `public` when rolling your own implementation.